# Converting a second order PDE from one coordinate system into another

Tags: differential-equations

I am interested in converting  a second order differential equation in partial derivatives from one coordinate system into another. To be specific from cylindrical coordinates to oblate spheroidal coordinates including the boundary conditions. can anyone give us a hand?

Comment: It would be nice to have the equation and its boundary conditions posted as Mathematica code as part of your question.

Comment: Is this a question about Wolfram Mathematica?